# how can I select the text in the parent node after the current tag in xsl?

Tags: xpath, xslt, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I have the following xsl:

```
<titleGroup>
            <title type="main" xml:lang="en">Synthesis of <i>N</i>‐Heterocyclic Carbenes and Their Complexes by
                Chloronium Ion Abstraction from 2‐Chloroazolium Salts Using Electron‐Rich Phosphines
            </title>
        </titleGroup>
```

if I'm at the template that calls "i" how can I check the value  "‐Heterocyclic Carbenes and Their Complexes by
Chloronium Ion Abstraction from 2‐Chloroazolium Salts Using Electron‐Rich Phosphines" in XSL I want the part which is after the current node only, not the part before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the context of `i`, the instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::text()[1]"/>
```

will return the value of the closest following sibling text node.